# Trek shift three rear 8 speed deraileur, in smallest cog the drive train seems to slip and re-engage in under a quarter turn?

Tags: hub

Recently I have a new shifter on handlebar, new cable, had the chain replaced and a new cassette and a new rear deraileur.
Wondering a about the Hub in the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Your question could be more detailed in regards to the model number/brand of the new shifter and derailleur.

Here's a few reasons one might experience slipping when in the small cog:

1. The most common cause of a new chain slipping is worn chainrings (front) or cassette cogs (rear).  Chains elongate with use due to wear of the pins. An overly worn chain will start to abnormally wear the teeth of the chainwheel and cassette cogs such that when a new chain is placed on the worn teeth, it will slip or ride over some teeth in the chainwheel or cog before reengaging. With drivetrains under 10 rear speeds, a chain can elongate to 0.75% before abnormal wear takes place. With higher rear speeds of today (10 to 12) a chain is considered worn out at 0.5% elongation.  You have not noted a change in the front drivetrain (the crank and it's chainring(s)). The new chain may possibly be slipping on some worn teeth of the chain ring. The only remedy is to replace the chainrings. On some lower-tier cranksets, this is not possible because the rings are permanently riveted to the spider. In these cases, and entirely new crankset is required.
2. The free hub body on the rear hub which holds the cassette and contains bearings and pawls may be worn or very dirty.  One or more of the pawls may hesitate or fail to spring out to engage the hub upon the initial pedal stroke after a freewheeling. This would cause a slipping feeling for the time it takes for the offending pawl to finally engage the hub. You could try to disassemble the freehub body from the hub and examine the and clean the pawls followed by regressing. You may also leave the body in place and direct a stream of aerosol spray lubricant into the joint where the body meets the rear hub.  Do not use regular WD-40 for this, as it is mostly solvent, has very little lubricant when it dries. Other products like TriFlow aerosol or WD-40 specialty lubes may be better suited to both free up gunky pawls and bring enough quality lubrication  to bear here.  Keep in mind that using any of these will cause any grease in the bearings to be diluted and or wash out.  This isn't a deal breaker necessarily to freeing up a stuck pawl. Especially in the face of minimal tools or knowledge to breakdown a hub and return it to functionality.
3. Here's what you may try first as it is the easiest to fix and access.  When a new derailleur is mounted, it has to be setup properly by setting the limit screws and indexing the gears (adjusting cable tension). You state the issue happens in the smallest rear cog. This is the high gear and the rear derailleur's H-limit screw controls how far out the derailleur cage can go. If it is too limited in it's outward movement, the chain may get onto the small cog but may at some points in the rotation try to climb on to the next larger cog but then fall back to the small cog. This would feel like slipping and would also be associated with noise.

The proper position of the upper, jockey wheel of the derailleur's cage when the cable is fully relaxed, is directly under the outside plane of the smallest cassette cog. In other words, if you were to extend the plane of the outer face of the small cog out, the tips of the teeth of the upper jockey wheel would be in that same plane. Looking at the derailleur from the rear, the cage should be nicely vertical and parallel to the plane of the cassette cogs, and when in high gear with no cable tension, the upper jockey wheel should appear to favor the outer face of the small cog.  Adjustment of the H-limit screw should be carried out to get this position. Counter clockwise rotation of the H limit screw will cause the jockey wheel to move more outward, clockwise rotation will move the jockey wheel more to the inside (further limiting it's outside movement).  Two important points: limit screws typically only need an ⅛ to ½ turn of adjustment to bring about a correct setting. Second is that the H-adjustment should be carried out in the ABSENCE of cable tension. For this you can disconnect the inner shift cable from the derailleurs pinch bolt or at the very least, turn the inner cable Barrell adjuster (found at the shifter right where the cable exits the shifter and sometimes, too, where the external shift housing joins the derailleur.  Turning the adjusters clockwise (tighter) causes the inner shift cable to become more slack, CCW rotation (looser) of the barrel adjuster gives the inner cable more tension.  Simply count the number of rotations clockwise you go with the barrel adjuster to get the slack inner cable, then turn the same number of rotations back CCW to return to the setting after you've adjusted the H-limit. Specifically, in your case, you may try to turn the H-limit screw CCW an 1/8th turn and see If that improves the slipping sensation.

Comment: Jeff, TY for a very detailed explanation. I had a spare wheel and decided to swap it out and it appears to have fixed the problem so I think the problem was the hub. I was surprised when replacing it with an identical rim that the brakes were dragging. I was in the testing ohase so I didn't want to spend a lot of time completing adjusting the caliper brake. I tried adjusting the barrel on the brake on the handlebar and the the screw on each side of the caliper. Not mush difference, seemed to get worse. Shoudn't this have been close enough to not have to adjust at all?

Comment: By the way, my symptom would occur on beginning to peddle after coasting but also would do it while peddling, just skip briefly and re-enegage. I was puzzled by the fact that it was just the small rear cog in combination with the middle gear of a 3 speed front gear assembly when all else seemed stable.

Comment: Regarding the brake drag, switching wheels can often require reindexing of the rear derailleur  and rim brake adjustment even when the parts are identical.  Factors such as variation in the dish (centering of the rim to the hub caused by spoke tension) and minor differences in the relative position of the hub within the dropouts caused by thickness and positioning of the cone-spacer-locknut assembly.  Basically differences of even 1 or 2 mm can have significant influence on the shifting (consider the effect of a few turns of a fine thread barrel adjuster has on shifting).

Comment: With rim brakes, a nominal distance between a brake pad and the rim's braking surface is 1.5 to 2 mm on each side.  Then factor in the slight position changes of the parts of a new rim installed, the variation in the rims set position within the dropouts (like with a QR skewer hub), and even changes in pad position caused by releasing the brake cable quick release and reconnecting it after install.  All can impart slight nuances to the system.

Comment: The timing of the slipping (especially  at the beginning pedal stroke after coasting) causes me to suspect a problem with a pawl being sticky so you're losing however many degrees of engagement it's responsible for.  I'll bet a good cleaning could resolve the issue for a lengthy period of time.  That said, freehub bodies are replaceable wear parts so there's always that option.

Comment: Thanks again, all comments helpfull